# How to remove Perl locale warning

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, locale

Is there any way to remove this when I run a perl script?
 I am running ubuntu.

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
            LANGUAGE = (unset),
            LC_ALL = (unset),
            LC_PAPER = "no_NO.UTF-8",
            LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Comment: Install the locales, as suggested by the error message.

Answer (score 6):

To get rid of the messages (by setting up the locales), run this command:

```sh
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
```

then

```sh
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually the error message referred to no_NO.UTF-8 rather than hu_HU  or hu_HU.UTF-8

Comment: Its just an example for understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Simply say `export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`, or put that into your `.profile`.